# Getting com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException

Tags: timeout, cluster-computing, hazelcast, member, operation

We are using Hazelcast as embedded in our spring boot application and our application is hosted on 12 tomcat servers forming a single cluster.

com.hazelcast.spi.properties.ClusterProperty.OPERATION_CALL_TIMEOUT_MILLIS  value is set to 8000

What could be the usual reason for such delays that hazelcast instances within the cluster taking more than 8sec to communicate?

Exception=com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException
GetOperation invocation failed to complete due to operation-heartbeat-timeout. Current time: 2023-11-21 03:46:33.437. Start time: 2023-11-21 03:46:16.441. Total elapsed time: 16996 ms. Last operation heartbeat: never. Last operation heartbeat from member: 2023-11-21 03:46:24.293. Invocation{op=com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService'

firstInvocationTimeMs=1700534776441, firstInvocationTime='2023-11-21 03:46:16.441', lastHeartbeatMillis=0, lastHeartbeatTime='1970-01-01 01:00:00.000', target=

What will be implications of increasing the value of OPERATION_CALL_TIMEOUT_MILLIS say to 20000

Comment: See the javadoc for operations results https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spi/impl/operationservice/impl/InvocationConstant.java#L28 The javadoc of heart beat time out is : Indicating that an operation is considered to be dead. So the system has no way of figuring out what happened to the operation or to its response.  It is not that the operation is rejected. It means there is a communication error